# How to send user information to zendesk?

Tags: zendesk

I have a zendesk support site at test.zendesk.com. I want to pass the following information to zendesk to be stored with each user's ticket:

- user id
- user browser information
- the page the user was on when they clicked on Support
- etc

Is there a way to securely send zendesk this information when users go to test.zendesk.com?

Comment: I recently saw this beta that may be useful for you, but it looks like I can't access the page right now, so I suggest contacting Zendesk support about it. From what I remember, the beta would allow you to capture page view data on pages which the web widget is installed: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207106547-Current-and-upcoming-Zendesk-betas#comment_205622888

Comment: For the user id, we set that using SSO authentication, which passes the user's id as the "external ID" attribute. More info on that here: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663816-Setting-up-single-sign-on-with-JWT-JSON-Web-Token-

Comment: For browser information, the UA string is stored on all tickets that are submitted via the web form, so that may work for you out of the box (click "show all events" in agent interface). We wanted something that was easier to read, so we created some fields on our web form, hid them using jQuery, and then parsed the user's UA string and added the results to the hidden fields on the form. It's a bit hacky and unstable, as Zendesk may decide to change the structure of the DOM without warning, but it works for now. Here's the UA parser library we used: https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js

Answer (score 0):

You could use Zendesk's API and with a custom HTML form pull this information into the form and then when submitting the form it sends it as an email to your Zendesk email address to create a ticket.

This is what has been done where i work.

Answer (score 0):

you could create custom ticket fields as zendesk allows to create custom fields. u can use API to post data to zendesk. To do this you have to submit data as agent, using api clients you can submit data to zendesk.

https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/tickets#create-ticket - for creating ticket vai curl

https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/api-clients/introduction - api clients